# Can not perform login opreation in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to login user in my application ,but i can't login.

I'm trying many way to resolve this issue but still not fixed.

Please tell me where I'm wrong .

Error is--

> Call to a member function attempt() on a non-object

ControllePage--

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Route;
use User;
use Hash;
use Auth;
use Input;
use Validator;
use Authenticatable;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Perform validations on user data
     * Hash Password
     * Create
     * @return Response
     */


    public function loginUserAuth() {


                $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
            'password' => 'required|min:5' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
        );

        // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            print_r($validator->messages());
              die;
            return Redirect::to('/login')
                ->withInput(Input::except('password')) // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
                ->with('errors',$validator->messages());
        } else {
            $userdata = array(
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'password'  =>  Hash::make('password')
            );
            // attempt to do the login
            if (Auth::user()->attempt($userdata,true)) {
                // validation successful!
                // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
                // return Redirect::to('secure');
                // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
              print_r("error");
              die;
                return Redirect::intended('/');
            } else {
                // validation not successful, send back to form
                print_r("error11");
              die;
                return Redirect::to('/login')->with('loginerrors','Invalid username or password');
            }
        }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an authenticated user yet, so you use:

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {...
```

Not:

```
if (Auth::user()->attempt($credentials)) {...
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: @aniruddh Please accept an answer if it's working for you

Answer (score 2):

this error is showing up because you are using Auth::user() which is returning null
try this:-

```
Auth::attempt($userdata)
```